# Activate a link click on page load based on anchor tag in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of links on a page that when clicked launch a lightbox-style pop-up (specifically [a issuu smartlook pdfs](http://issuu.com/smartlook) in several languages).  I am trying to figure out a way to cause these to automatically open on page load, but only when there is an anchor tag in the url.

**example.com/page** would load the page normally

**example.com/page#english**  would make the English version pop up on page load

**example.com/page#french** would make the French version pop up, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Could use jquery to check the hash on window.location, and do something based on that:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
        $('#' + window.location.hash).click();  
        //assumes you have an element with id='english', id='french', etc
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!  This gets me extremely close, but I'm still not quite there: I'm running into problems with .click() triggering links properly.  
For testing, I was using a link like this:   
`<a onclick="window.alert('CLICK!');" id="foo" href="#">link</a>`  
and the onlcick event would trigger the alert, as expected.  
  
Once I get rid of the onclick event, and just want the link to act as if it is being normally clicked, a click is not registered. This link:  
`<a id="foo" href="example.com">link</a>`   
doesn't trigger anything, while the other link does.

Comment: I also discovered it should just be $(window.location.hash).click(); - window.location.hash already returns the value with the # before it, so '#' + window.location.hash would have 2 hashes before.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified SarahBourt's code to then display the modal. This helped me out, figured I'd share.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
    $(window.location.hash).modal('toggle');
    //assumes you have an element with id='english', id='french', etc
}
});
```